# Wordpress newsletter plugin that composes from posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins, posts, newsletter

I am looking for a Wordpress newsletter plugin which allows me to compose newsletter from WP posts. So far I have found only one (https://www.thenewsletterplugin.com/), but I was wondering if anyone knows of another one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a look at [MailPoet](https://www.mailpoet.com/) (former Wysija)